# How to make labels print on SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

Trying to get `use_labels=True` to work on this query below...but the library keeps spitting errors....i'm doing this complicated join and need to see the labels on the columns to try and grab the data.  I know i shouldn't be using an ORM session to `execute()` but frankly, idc at this point and just want to get it to work.  I have given up on ORM...doesnt work with the query below:

```
data = DBSession.execute(text("SELECT \
                        * \
                        FROM \
                        art_packs \
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN \
                        art_pack_pieces AS art_pack_pieces_1 ON art_packs.art_pack_id = art_pack_pieces_1.art_pack_id \
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN \
                        art_pack_pieces_artists AS art_pack_pieces_artists_1 ON art_pack_pieces_1.art_pack_piece_id = art_pack_pieces_artists_1.art_pack_piece_id \
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN \
                        users ON art_pack_pieces_artists_1.artist_id = users.id \
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN \
                        art_pack_pieces as art_pack_pieces_2 ON art_packs.cover_id = art_pack_pieces_2.art_pack_piece_id \
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN \
                        art_pack_pieces_likes as art_pack_pieces_likes_1 ON art_pack_pieces_1.art_pack_piece_id = art_pack_pieces_likes_1.art_pack_piece_id AND art_pack_pieces_likes_1.artist_id = " + str(artistID) + " \
                        WHERE art_packs.art_pack_id = " + id, use_labels=True)).fetchall()
```

Query ain't the safest..but the int's are already validated so nothing wrong with what i'm doing i suppose.

Thanks.

Comment: I would assume that [sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) does not support `use_labels` parameter.